# Stripping trailing slash in URL doesn't work in subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

The following rule works to remove the trailing slash for all pages in my web root:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

However, it does not work when placed in a sub folder. I've also tried:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

to no avail. What happens is, it redirects

http://example.com/testfolder/testpage/

to

http://example.com/testpage

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a direct comparison, it's good practice only to change one thing at a time. I see you changed `.+` to `.*` *in addition to* removing `^`. Not necessarily the root of the world's problems, but it'll help keep you saner, longer, if there's only one variable at a time.

Comment: @Chris Thanks, I appreciate the tip. I actually got both of those lines from other SO posts. I'm new to programming and still don't understand regular expressions. I just picked up PHP a few months ago, and am learning as I go. I suppose I should take the time to learn regular expressions as I've heard that they can be very powerful, and they seem to be used everywhere.

Comment: Sure thing (and welcome to Stack Overflow!). Can you explain what you mean by "when placed in a sub folder"? Do you mean you're creating an .htaccess file in the subdirectory? Or just that you want a single `RewriteRule` to work on all [sub]directories of your site?

Comment: Also, you're correct - regular expressions some one of the most powerful (and I think fun) tools we have. It'd be smart to learn them well so that you can use them, but it would be wise to learn why/when/where **not** to use them. Fortunately for this discussion, `RewriteRule` is an appropriate place. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried omitting the leading slash from your replacement?

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
```

It's just a stone's throw from what you have. The context of the directory rewrite (being "in" /testfolder) may be the root cause of the trouble.

Comment: I'd like to automatically remove it just to keep my site consistent. Currently I only one sub folder but that may change (this is my first website). Any idea how I can modify the above to not strip the subfolder from the URL?

Comment: @JackT - I've updated to reflect a recent brainwave, it may just help. You should also investigate @Kaz's answer to see if `mod_dir` could be toying with the request (regarding re-adding the trailing slash) after `mod_rewrite` has done it's job.

Comment: Thanks for keeping on top of this! I ended up taking the time to figure out what that regular expression was doing and modifying it to fit my needs in the other folder. That one is very simple, but it's amazing how complex regular expressions can get. I have a feeling that this isn't something learned overnight. All in all, I've been actively programming for about a year and I love when everything finally works! I seem to do my best programming while riding my bike or in between dreams at night, when my subconscious can go to work. Anyway, thanks again for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

you may be able to define this in variables also make sure Rewrite mods are enabled in your php.ini if there is no other way of doing what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The trailing slash fixup is being done by `mod_dir`. Rewrites in your per-directory context are re-injected into the URL processing chain and subject to the fixup again.

The behavior is configurable. E.g.

```
<Directory /path/to/wherever>
DirectorySlash Off
...
</Directory>
```

The context for this is not only `Directory`: it is server config, virtual host, directory, .htaccess.